# Using param values as position

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several XML documents where each document is one chapter from a book. All these files are merged into one DOMDocument where `<book>` is added as root element.

The DOMDocument gets the following structure:

```
<book>
<chapter title="This is the first chapter">
    <section title="This is the first section">
    <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
    </section>
    </chapter>
<chapter title="This is the second chapter">
    <section title="This is the first section">
    <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
    </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

I'm successfully making a table of contents where I can select chapters with link with querystring (ie. default.php?chapter=1). When I try to open a chapter, the param "chapter" is set to the querystring.

How can I successfully show the chapter that is equal to the querystring? I get a problem with setting the position from the param. I get an "Undefined variable" error. But no errors when I use it in value-of.

```
<xsl:param name="chapter" />

    <xsl:template match="//chapter[$chapter]">
            <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="$chapter"/> - <xsl:value-of select="@title"/></title>
            </head>
            <body>              
        <h1>
            Chapter <xsl:value-of select="$chapter"/> <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

So, what I want is that when the user visits "default.php?chapter=1" he gets the only chapter 1 like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chapter 1 - This is chapter 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Chapter 1 - This is chapter 1</h1>
blablablablablablabla
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't use variables in <xsl:template match="">. I do not understand what you try to achieve. CAn you post the target XML you expect please?

Comment: I updated my question with what I want as result. I only want to show 1 chapter based on the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this XSLT to your source XML:

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

```
<xsl:param name="chosenChapter" select="'1'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book/chapter[position() = $chosenChapter]"/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:param name="chapter" select="@title"/>
    
    
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="$chosenChapter"/> - <xsl:value-of select="$chapter"/></title>
        </head>
        <body>              
            <h1>
                Chapter <xsl:value-of select="$chosenChapter"/> <xsl:value-of select="$chapter"/>
            </h1>
            <text>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </text>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <html>
            <head>
                    <title>1 - This is the first chapter</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <h1> Chapter 1This is the first chapter</h1>
                    <text> This is the paragraph content </text>
            </body>
    </html>
</list>
```

I edited my question. I hope this helps. In `<xsl:template match=""` you can't add variables but you can in `<xsl:apply-templates select=""`. The `chosenChapter` is hard coded to "1" in my example.